# conditional filter in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have two arrays and first array are having keys and want to check that all keys are having second array with value true. and return that true value array.

i have code as like below

```
const keysArray = ['phoneNo', 'name']

const data = [{ demo1:'abc', match_status:{ phoneNo: true, name: null }}, { demo2:'abc', match_status_flag:{ phoneNo: true, name: true }}]
```

My expected output as like below:

```
const outputArray = [{ demo2:'abc', match_status_flag:{ phoneNo: true, name: true }}]
```

i tried code as like below but not getting expected output

```
keysArray.map((k) => data.filter(i => i.match_status[k] === true))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a common property, like `match_status_flag` and filter the data.

```js
const
    keys = ['phoneNo', 'name'],
    data = [{ demo1: 'abc', match_status_flag: { phoneNo: true, name: null } }, { demo2: 'abc', match_status_flag: { phoneNo: true, name: true } }],
    result = data.filter(({ match_status_flag }) =>
        keys.every(k => match_status_flag[k])
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```